# Share Button on Action Bar?

Tags: android

I am currently building an app where I need to share an image. I have done the XML and the share button appears, but you can't click on it.

Here is my code for the button in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_scan"
          android:icon="@drawable/scanlogo"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          android:title="Scan" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          android:title="Share"
          android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
</menu>
```

This is where I inflate the menu:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_share_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

This all works and it shows up, but it is not clickable. Here is where I try to make it clickable:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_item_share:
                Intent ShareIntent = new Intent();
                String pathofBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), QRMap,"QRCode", null);
                Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(pathofBmp);
                ShareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                ShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);


  ShareIntent.setType("image/png");
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(ShareIntent);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `R.id.menu_item_share` case of your `onOptionsItemSelected()` method. Move that code elsewhere in your app, such as `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, to configure the `ShareActionProvider` before it is displayed.

For example, here is an activity that configures a `ShareActionProvider`, from [one of my sample projects](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/Share):

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.sap;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity implements
    ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener, TextWatcher {
  private ShareActionProvider share=null;
  private Intent shareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  private EditText editor=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    editor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editor);
    editor.addTextChangedListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);

    share=
        (ShareActionProvider)menu.findItem(R.id.share)
                                 .getActionProvider();
    share.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(this);

    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source,
                                       Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(this, intent.getComponent().toString(),
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return(false);
  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, editor.getText());
    share.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                int after) {
    // ignored
  }

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                            int count) {
    // ignored
  }
}
```

In my case, this is using ActionBarSherlock, but the same process holds for the native action bar.

Comment: Still nothing, forgot to add it doesnt even light up when I click its dead.

Comment: @SteveSmith: I can tell you that my sample app works, on any device that has something that supports sharing of `text/plain`.

Comment: I am trying to do an Image

Comment: @SteveSmith: Do you have any apps on your device that support `ACTION_SEND` for `image/png`? If not, there is your problem. If you do, then examine my code again and see where mine differs from yours.